# The accuracy of basic Tensorflow model not increasing

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am really new to Data Science/ML and have been working on Tensorflow to implement Linear Regression on [California Housing Prices](https://www.kaggle.com/camnugent/california-housing-prices) from Kaggle.

I tried to train a mode in two different ways:

1. Using a Sequential model
2. Custom implementation

In both cases, the loss of the model was really high and I have not been able to understand what are the ways to improve it.

- ### Dataset prep

```py
df = pd.read_csv('california-housing-prices.zip')

df = df[['total_rooms', 'total_bedrooms', 'median_house_value', 'housing_median_age', 'median_income']]

print('Shape of dataset before removing NAs and duplicates {}'.format(df.shape))
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
input_train, input_test, target_train, target_test = train_test_split(df['total_rooms'].values, df['median_house_value'].values, test_size=0.2)
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
input_train = input_train.reshape(-1,1)
input_test = input_test.reshape(-1,1)
input_train = scaler.fit_transform(input_train)
input_test = scaler.fit_transform(input_test)
target_train = target_train.reshape(-1,1)
target_train = scaler.fit_transform(target_train)
target_test = target_test.reshape(-1,1)
target_test = scaler.fit_transform(target_test)
print('Number of training input elements {}'.format(input_train.shape))
print('Number of training target elements {}'.format(target_train.shape))
```

- ### Using `Sequential` API:

```py
BATCH_SIZE = 10
BUFFER = 5000

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((input_train, target_train))

dataset = dataset.shuffle(BUFFER).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

DENSE_UNITS = 64
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(DENSE_UNITS, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(DENSE_UNITS, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

EPOCH = 5000

early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=5)

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001), loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy', 'mse'])
history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=EPOCH, callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

- Final training metrics -

```
Epoch 1/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 13s 8ms/step - loss: 0.0564 - accuracy: 0.0013 - mse: 0.0564
Epoch 2/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0552 - accuracy: 0.0016 - mse: 0.0552
Epoch 3/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0551 - accuracy: 0.0012 - mse: 0.0551
Epoch 4/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0551 - accuracy: 9.1766e-04 - mse: 0.0551
Epoch 5/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0551 - accuracy: 0.0013 - mse: 0.0551
Epoch 6/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0551 - accuracy: 0.0013 - mse: 0.0551
Epoch 7/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0549 - accuracy: 0.0013 - mse: 0.0549
Epoch 8/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0550 - accuracy: 0.0012 - mse: 0.0550
Epoch 9/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0549 - accuracy: 0.0011 - mse: 0.0549
Epoch 10/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0550 - accuracy: 0.0012 - mse: 0.0550
Epoch 11/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0549 - accuracy: 0.0010 - mse: 0.0549
Epoch 12/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0549 - accuracy: 0.0011 - mse: 0.0549
Epoch 13/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0549 - accuracy: 0.0013 - mse: 0.0549
Epoch 14/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0549 - accuracy: 0.0016 - mse: 0.0549
Epoch 15/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0549 - accuracy: 0.0011 - mse: 0.0549
Epoch 16/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0549 - accuracy: 0.0017 - mse: 0.0549
Epoch 17/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0549 - accuracy: 0.0013 - mse: 0.0549
Epoch 18/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0549 - accuracy: 6.1177e-04 - mse: 0.0549
Epoch 19/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0549 - accuracy: 6.1177e-04 - mse: 0.0549
Epoch 20/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0549 - accuracy: 6.1177e-04 - mse: 0.0549
Epoch 21/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0549 - accuracy: 0.0012 - mse: 0.0550
Epoch 22/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0548 - accuracy: 9.7883e-04 - mse: 0.0549
Epoch 23/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0550 - accuracy: 7.3412e-04 - mse: 0.0549
Epoch 24/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0549 - accuracy: 7.9530e-04 - mse: 0.0549
Epoch 25/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0548 - accuracy: 0.0013 - mse: 0.0548
Epoch 26/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0549 - accuracy: 7.9530e-04 - mse: 0.0549
Epoch 27/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0549 - accuracy: 6.7295e-04 - mse: 0.0549
Epoch 28/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0548 - accuracy: 0.0012 - mse: 0.0548
Epoch 29/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0549 - accuracy: 0.0013 - mse: 0.0549
Epoch 30/5000
1635/1635 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0548 - accuracy: 9.7883e-04 - mse: 0.0549
```

- ### Using custom training

```py
class Linear(object):

  def __init__(self):
    """ 
    Y = mX + C

    Initializing the intercet and the slope
    """
    self.m = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape=()))
    self.C = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape=()))

  def __call__(self, x):
    return self.m * x + self.C

# Defining a MSE loss function
def loss(predicted_y, target_y):
  return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(predicted_y - target_y))


def train(model, input, output, learning_rate):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    predicted_y = model(input)
    current_loss = loss(predicted_y, output)
    df_m, df_C = tape.gradient(current_loss, [model.m, model.C])

    model.m.assign_sub(learning_rate * df_m)
    model.C.assign_sub(learning_rate * df_C)

epochs = 5000
model = Linear()
print(model.m.assign_sub(1))
ms, Cs, losses = [], [], []
target_train = target_train.astype('float32')
for epoch in range(epochs):
  ms.append(model.m.numpy())
  Cs.append(model.C.numpy())
  predicted_y = model(input_train)
  current_loss = loss(predicted_y, target_train)
  losses.append(current_loss)
  train(model, input_train, target_train, 0.1)
  if epoch % 500 == 0:
    print('Epoch %2d: W=%1.2f b=%1.2f, loss=%2.5f' %
        (epoch, ms[-1], Cs[-1], current_loss))

predicted_test = model(input_test[:10])

print(np.argmax(predicted_test.numpy()))
print(scaler.inverse_transform(predicted_test))
print(scaler.inverse_transform(target_test[:10]))
predicted_loss = loss(predicted_test, target_test[:10])

print(predicted_loss.numpy())
```

- Final training metrics

```
Epoch  0: W=-1.86 b=-0.09, loss=0.44381
Epoch 500: W=-1.19 b=0.47, loss=0.06470
Epoch 1000: W=-0.73 b=0.44, loss=0.06034
Epoch 1500: W=-0.39 b=0.42, loss=0.05799
Epoch 2000: W=-0.13 b=0.40, loss=0.05671
Epoch 2500: W=0.05 b=0.39, loss=0.05602
Epoch 3000: W=0.19 b=0.38, loss=0.05565
Epoch 3500: W=0.29 b=0.38, loss=0.05545
Epoch 4000: W=0.36 b=0.37, loss=0.05534
Epoch 4500: W=0.41 b=0.37, loss=0.05528
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, you shouldn't reshape your input into 1D. You transformed your matrix into a long 1D array. So, remove these lines:

```
input_train = input_train.reshape(-1,1)
input_test = input_test.reshape(-1,1)
```

Then you will keep the 8 features of your input data. Then, change the first lines of your model like this:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.Input(shape=(8,)),
```

Your loss will decrease. After a few epochs I get this:

```
1644/1652 [============================>.] - 
ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0144 - accuracy: 0.0434 - mse: 0.0144
```

**I couldn't use your `.zip` file so I did it differently. Here is all my reproducible code:**

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf

from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
x, y = fetch_california_housing(return_X_y=True)

input_train, _, target_train, _ = train_test_split(x, y)
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
input_train = scaler.fit_transform(input_train)
target_train = target_train.reshape(-1,1)
target_train = scaler.fit_transform(target_train)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((input_train, target_train))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(5000).batch(32)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.Input(shape=(8,)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)])

early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=5)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001),
    loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy', 'mse'])
history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=50, callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

Comment: What if I keep the number of input features less say around two, in this case, how can I improve the accuracy and drop loss. Also, why shouldn't I reshape the input to 1D?

Comment: You shouldn't reshape because your input doesn't make sense anymore. You had, say, 5,000 examples with 8 features each. Flattening it means that your rows are not houses with features anymore. Also, you shouldn't rescale your target. To increase accuracy you can add a dropout layer, more neurons, and more layers.

Comment: Thanks, not reshaping my data did bring the accuracy to `0.0434` but don't you think it is still less, as it is around 4.32% which is quite less. I do understand the number of data points is also less but is there any way to improve the accuracy.

Comment: I don't knw. But that's not accuracy, because you're not classifying. So you're minimizing the error. Accuracy is the number of samples that are correctly classified.